# Does UDP Port 1434 need to be open for named instances with static TCP?

Tags: sql-server, network, dynamic-ports

I have built a named instance which is running on a static port, 50101.

The network guys have opened the port on the firewall to allow incoming connections. I have asked them open UDP port 1434 too, as I believe the SQL Browser Service runs on this port and needs to pass the correct port for the named instance back to the requesting connection. Even if the named instance is running on a static TCP port.

Is that correct?

SQL Browser / UDP 1434 is not just for dynamic ports, right?

It needs to be open if the port is not explicit in the connection string?

Really need to end this argument!

MP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UDP 1434 is used for Named SQL Server instances and SQL Browser service listens on this port for any incoming requests to a named sql server instance. The browser service will respond to the client with TCP port no. for the requested named instance.

[From BOL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175043(v=sql.110).aspx) :

> The SQL Server Browser service lets users connect to instances of the Database Engine that are not listening on port 1433, without knowing the port number.
>
> To use SQL Server Browser, you must open UDP port 1434. To promote the **most secure environment**, leave the SQL Server Browser service stopped, and **configure clients to connect using the port number**.

-

> It needs to be open if the port is not explicit in the connection string?

Yes. If browser service is not running, you HAVE to specify `servername,portNo` e.g. `YourSecureSQLServerName,50101`

Answer (score 2):

If the port is static (which it appears to be), you can simply connect to port 50101 using `tcp:<ip address of sql server/NAT/firewall>,50101` in your connection string.  For example:

```
tcp:192.168.0.101,50101
```

You don't need 1434 open through the firewall, and some might consider that a dead giveaway that you have a SQL Server on 50101.

If you don't want to provide the port number in the connection string, then you could provide access to the SQL Browser service on UDP 1434, or you could, if using NAT to provide access to the SQL Server, open port 1433 and redirect it to 50101, and just use the name of the server in the connection string (i.e. no instance name).

Comment: I'll ask my network admin about NAT, thanks so much for the information.

Answer (score 1):

1. sql service check
2. use ssms change sql logon mmode  do mix mode
3. use ssms tcp enable